# Upload image using Amazon PreSigned URL gives status code 400 everytime iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

**Point :**

- I am working on uploading image using Amazon Pre-Signed URL in my iOS App
- Now the issue is i am getting status code 400 everytime when i upload it
- It should give 204 status code if it works well
- Pre-Signed URL works well while testing on Postman but not working on App side.

**Here is the implementation :**

```
- (void)doUploadURL {
    UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage);

    NSString *boundary = @"---011000010111000001101001";
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
    // AcL parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"acl\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strAcL dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Content-Type parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Content-Type\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strContentType dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // key parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strKey dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // x-amz-meta-filename parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"x-amz-meta-filename\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strMetaFilename dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // X-Amz-Credential parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"X-Amz-Credential\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strCredential dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // X-Amz-Algorithm parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"X-Amz-Algorithm\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strAlgorithm dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // X-Amz-Date parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"X-Amz-Date\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strAmzDate dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Policy parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Policy\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strPolicy dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // X-Amz-Signature parameter
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"X-Amz-Signature\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[strSignature dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // file
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Disposition: attachment; name=\"file\"; filename=\"testimage.png\"\\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSDictionary *headers = @{ @"content-type": @"multipart/form-data"};
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://visual-showcase.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3600.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:headers];
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
        NSLog(@" Final Response : %d",httpResponse.statusCode);

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error :  %@", error);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Failed to upload" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
                return;
            });
        } else {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

            NSError *err = nil;
            NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

**Response code :**

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x7d10e2c0> { status code: 400, headers {
    Connection = close;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml";
    Date = "Thu, 02 Feb 2017 07:20:18 GMT";
    Server = AmazonS3;
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "x-amz-id-2" = "HIFhwBaj/ejjGoCgD2vacG2AtoxEFDXxSr6eulZtzUbuLoTcLT+AA9k6093Jyv5OIuK2wpi7+9c=";
    "x-amz-request-id" = C221CD8DA2D80BCD;
} }
```

**Question :**

- My question is, is there anything we need to set while uploading files using Amazon Pre-Signed URL ? Or we can just implement it like normal API calls ?
- As per my knowledge & it should be implemented similar way like normal APIs
- Please do let me get any hint or if something wrong i am doing in request format

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Just one question: Why don't you simply use the SDK from Amazon:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/s3-pre-signed-urls.html ?

Comment: @AndreasOetjen actually, pre-signed URL is generated from server Side coding & than client provides it through one API & that i will have to use here for upload file. So can say half of the process is on server side.

Comment: Try using PUT instead of POST.

Comment: I'm not an expert in HTTP protocol, but I see a few problems with your approach: First the boundary: Where do you specify it in the HTTP header? What happens if (by co-incidence) some of your data contains just the boundary string? 
Therefore, I just would recomment using the SDK (and I'm not sure why you shouldn't be able to use the SDK; definetly the URL is generated on server side, but you just use it on the client side).

Comment: @AndreasOetjen earlier it was specified in the header, So already tried with that one but not worked so i removed it

Comment: Its a POST request so how can use PUT, One more thing its already tried & tested on Postman using POST & it works fine there, Just the thing is its not working from App

Comment: Maybe you should just output the HTTP Request string and check if it's reasonable. Then, use telnet and put your string into it to check what happens. Maybe you could also use Postman for this, unfortunately I don't know this tool.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen i am not aware about how to use telnet & investigate the issue. But i am using Postman which generates the code for almost every languages which we can directly use in the app.

Comment: Now since status 400 indicates a bad request, I would assume something is wrong within the HTTP protocol - maybe caused by the generated could. Sorry, but I cannot help any further.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen thanks i will change the request format & will try

Comment: Note that this question is not actually about a *pre-signed URL* at all.  This is a *form `POST` upload with a signed policy document*.  I believe the question should be edited to reflect this, for the benefit of future visitors with a similar problem (which is an entirely different can of worms from pre-signed URLs).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue by changing the request parameters format. Below is the working code.

```
- (void)doUploadURL {
    UIImage *myimage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.png"];
    NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myimage);

    NSString *boundary = @"------VohpleBoundary4QuqLuM1cE5lMwCy";
    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    //Populate a dictionary with all the regular values you would like to send.
    NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [parameters setValue:strAcL forKey:@"acl"];
    [parameters setValue:strContentType forKey:@"Content-Type"];
    [parameters setValue:strKey forKey:@"key"];
    [parameters setValue:strMetaFilename forKey:@"x-amz-meta-filename"];
    [parameters setValue:strCredential forKey:@"X-Amz-Credential"];
    [parameters setValue:strAlgorithm forKey:@"X-Amz-Algorithm"];
    [parameters setValue:strAmzDate forKey:@"X-Amz-Date"];
    [parameters setValue:strPolicy forKey:@"Policy"];
    [parameters setValue:strSignature forKey:@"X-Amz-Signature"];

    // add params (all params are strings)
    for (NSString *param in parameters) {
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", param] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
        [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r\n", [parameters objectForKey:param]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    }

    // Upload image
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"testimage.png\"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"Content-Type:image/png\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:imageData];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    //Close off the request with the boundary
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"APIURL"] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:3600.0];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    // set Content-Type in HTTP header
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
    [request setValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;

        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error :  %@", error);
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Failed to upload" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
                return;
            });
        } else {
            NSHTTPURLResponse *httpResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *) response;
            NSError *err = nil;
            NSDictionary *responseDic = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];
        }
    }];
    [dataTask resume];
}
```

Hope it will help guiding someone.